# How to apply different easing effects to sprite action?

Tags: ios, ios7, sprite-kit

I use a lot of `CCEase*` functionalities in **Cocos2D** described [here](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aactions_ease). iOS 7 **Sprite Kit** also have `SKActionTimingMode`. However only simple modes. How can I get `CCEaseElasticIn` or `CCEaseBounceIn` like effects using **Sprite Kit**?

Comment: I guess Apple wants us to use customActionWith... for cases like these.

Comment: Do you have any clue how to make that happen with `customActionWith`?

Comment: only conceptually, the general idea is to use the elapsedTime as well as the duration and feed both into an easing action to determine how much the desired property (ie position) should change at any given elapsedTime. The easing function you could adapt from cocos2d for example.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sprite Kit left easing (or tweening) intentionally limited with the expectation that the developer would take control of the specifics of the motion of the sprites.  Basically, what you need to do is make a custom action and apply an easing curve to the parameter before changing the property (rotation, position, scale, etc) of the sprite.  Here's an example.

```
CGFloat initialScale = mySprite.xScale;
SKAction *scaleAction = [SKAction customActionWithDuration:duration actionBlock:^(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime) {
  CGFloat t = elapsedTime/duration;
  CGFloat p = t*t;
  CGFloat s = initialScale*(1-p) + scale * p;
  [node setScale:s];
}];
[mySprite runAction:scaleAction];
```

The part of this that determines the easing is `p = t*t`.  So, `p` is a function of `t` such that :

- when `t` is 0, `p` is 0
- when `t` is 1, `p` is 1

That means that you will start at the beginning and end at the end but the shape of the curve in between will determine how you get there.  Easing functions can be simple, like the one shown here, which is basically an ease-in, or quite complex such as elastic or bounce.  To generate your own, try this : http://www.timotheegroleau.com/Flash/experiments/easing_function_generator.htm
Or take a more detailed look at Robert Penner's equations: http://www.robertpenner.com/easing/

Comment: another good link for the mathematical implementation of the different easing function types is at: https://github.com/warrenm/AHEasing

Comment: How would we apply this to `SKAction followPath`?

Answer (score 2):

For arbitrary easing, Kardasis' answer says it all.

If you're looking for an easy way to add a bouncing effect to your animations, that is consistent with the way things are done in UIKit, I have something for you.

Apple introduced spring animations in UIKit a couple years ago, by letting you set a spring damping and initial velocity when performing a UIView animation. Unfortunately they didn't implement that in SpriteKit, so I made my own library that does just that.

It's a set of extensions on SKAction that replicate most factory methods, adding the damping and velocity parameters.

The code is on GitHub, feel free to use it: https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring