# SpriteKit SKAction easing

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Well the title gives the question away, how can I apply easing to the SKAction node actions in SpriteKit?

I found that this works:

```
SKAction *moveAction = [SKAction moveByX:moveX y:moveY duration:0.5];
moveAction.timingMode = SKActionTimingEaseInEaseOut;
[node runAction:moveAction];
```

However there are only a few easing types available [there](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html), namely Linear, EaseIn, EaseOut, EaseInOut.

And those easing values are fixed and cannot be altered. I am looking for something like EleasticInOut. With preferably a bit more control. How can I create that?

Comment: Action Timing Modes are listed under constants guess we stuck with what apple has for now

Comment: I think you should use a custom action for that.Also I think your question is already answered on this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026895/how-to-apply-different-easing-effects-to-sprite-action

Comment: Does anyone know how to completely turn off easing on an SkAction? I would think this to be quite an important property but maybe not...

Comment: @ObjectiveCsam - "linear" is no easing (ie, it moves from point a to point b linearly rather than more slowly at the start or end).

Answer (score 15):

I've been using the SKEase framework:
https://github.com/buddingmonkey/SpriteKit-Easing
It's as simple to use as the standard SpriteKit Actions and adds all the usual more complex eases, cubic, bounce, elastic, back etc.
SpriteKitUtils also adds more complex easing types and some handy SpriteKit utilities: https://github.com/raywenderlich/SKTUtils

The other option is to roll your own using the custom action method, and pass it a block of code with your custom easing/animation function:

```
-(SKAction *)customActionWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)seconds actionBlock:(void (^)(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime))block
```

Answer (score 11):

Apple introduced spring animations in UIKit a couple years ago, by letting you set a spring damping and initial velocity when performing a UIView animation. Unfortunately they didn't implement that in SpriteKit, so I made my own library that does just that.

It's a set of extensions on SKAction that replicate most factory methods, adding the damping and velocity parameters.

The code is on GitHub, feel free to use it: https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring

Answer (score 0):

Here is fresh, as spring water, answer goes. In iOS 8 [`timingFunction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417666-timingfunction) was introduced. It allows you to create custom timing curves.

> The return SKActionTimingFunction value of the timing function
> determines the actual time used to perform the animation.

This way, you can implement your own easing function. Although it has certain limitations: output values must be between 0.0 and 1.0. So for more realistic elastic bouncing I would recommend use [`SpriteKit-Spring`](https://github.com/ataugeron/SpriteKit-Spring)